# Keep getting Warning message: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r

I believe that I've read the files appropriately, however, when calculating the mean, I get a warning message that the arguments in my mean function are not numeric.  Yet, when I str the files, they are clearly the numeric class.  I've also removed all the NAs to calculate the mean.  I have been searching everywhere for possible solutions, but have not yet found any.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
pollutantmean <- function(specdata, pollutant, id=1:332) {

    ## set up the directory
    specdata <- setwd("~/Programming Exercise/specdata")

    ## read the files
    listfile <- dir(pattern = "*.csv")
    for (i in 1:length(listfile)) {
            temp[[i]] <- read.csv(listfile[i], header=TRUE)
    }

    ## calculate the mean function
    pollutant <- if(pollutant=="nitrate") {
            mean(temp[["nitrate"]], na.rm=TRUE)
    } else {
            mean(temp[["sulfate"]], na.rm=TRUE)
    }
}
```

Comment: Each `temp[[i]]` is an object of class `"data.frame"`. You cannot compute `mean(dfrm)`, it is not numeric nor logical, it's a special kind of list.

Comment: I ran a mean function on a single file to try to get through this warning error, but it doesn't work either.  How does one read a csv file and the columns read as numerics?

Comment: 1) Please reread my first comment, no matter what is in the df, `mean` will not work. There are `rowMeans` and `colMeans`, if that's what you need. You should explain better if you want the overall mean. 2) Check the contents of each df with `str(temp[[i]])`. Maybe you could post one of the outputs.

Comment: Do you have any sample of data to share? Also like Rui Barradas said, are you looking for a simple column mean? Overall mean? Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to get a simple mean of the column nitrate or sulfate, so when I run: 

pollutantmean(temp, "nitrate", 1)

I get:
Warning message:
In mean.default(temp[["nitrate"]], na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Running the str function:

> str(temp[[i]])
'data.frame': 731 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Date   : Factor w/ 731 levels "2003-01-01","2003-01-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ sulfate: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ nitrate: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ID     : int  332 332 332 332 332 332 332 332 332 332 ...
>

Comment: Never mind.  I was taking a beginner class in R, but I'm clearly not even a beginner.  I've decided to quit the class.